# for loop here is not working i am using bluetooth serial connection

Tags: loops, if-statement, for-loop, arduino

```
void loop() // run over and over 
{
    while (!mySerial.available()); // stay here so long as COM port is empty
    receivedChar = mySerial.read();

    if (receivedChar == '1')
    {
        digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
        for (int i=0; i<500; i++) 
        {
            digitalWrite(buz, HIGH);
            delayMicroseconds(500);
            digitalWrite(buz, LOW);
            delayMicroseconds(500); 
        }
    }// if it's a 1 turn LED on

    if (receivedChar == '2')
    {
        digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
    } // if it's a 2 turn LED off
} // if it is a 3 flash the LED
```

here "forloop" is not looping please help for this

Comment: let me try to see if I understand you problem: if you receive a `1` then you want the LED to go into a blinking mode which you want to interrupt when you receive a `2`?

Comment: Yes you are right when it receives "2" then blinking should stop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT with completely new answer:

Ok, I hope I understand your problem better. If you want to have the LED blinking until you receive a corresponding other command, you can do something like this (not explicitly tested):

Another edit: from your comment on the question I seem to understand that you want to toggle on and off the blinking whenever you are sending `1`? If that that's the case, you can maybe add another boolean to the check which you toggle when you send a `1`.

```
void loop() // run over and over 
{
    static bool active = false;
    static char receivedChar = '0';
    if (mySerial.available()) { 
        receivedChar = mySerial.read();
        // if you received a 1, change the state of the 'active' boolean
        if (receivedChar == '1')
        {
            active = !active;
        }
    }



    // only perform the action on receiving 1 
    // only when also the boolean is set to the correct value
    if (receivedChar == '1' && active)
    {
            digitalWrite(buz, HIGH);
            delay(100);
            digitalWrite(buz, LOW);
            delay(100); 
    }// if it's a 1 turn LED on

    if (receivedChar == '2')
    {
        digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
    } // if it's a 2 turn LED off
} // if it is a 3 flash the LED
```

declaring `receivedChar` as static should keep its value the same for the next iteration of `loop`. This means that the `loop` will run and if you sent a `1` it will always enter the `if (receivedChar == '1')` condition and switch the LED on and off with whatever delay you choose and then simply repeat this until you send another character, e.g. 2 at which point he will enter condition `if (receivedChar == '2')`, switches off the LED and will simply go back to `if (receivedChar == '2')` until you send something else again.

Does this help?

Yet another edit:

with an arduino and a LED connected to pin 3, the following sketch does what you are asking:

Send `1` over the serial port, the LED starts blinking. Send another `1`, the blinking stops. If you send a `2`, the blinking also stops.

If this sketch does not show the behavior described above, then you are doing something in your code that you are not disclosing.

```
int LED = 3;

// the setup routine runs once when you press reset:
void setup() {      
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // initialize the digital pin as an output.
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);     
}


void loop() // run over and over 
{
    static bool active = false;
    static char receivedChar = '0';
    if (Serial.available()) { 
        receivedChar = Serial.read();
        // if you received a 1, change the state of the 'active' boolean
        if (receivedChar == '1')
        {
            active = !active;
        }
    }



    // only perform the action on receiving 1 
    // only when also the boolean is set to the correct value
    if (receivedChar == '1' && active)
    {
            digitalWrite(LED,HIGH);  
            delay(100);
            digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
            delay(100); 
    }// if it's a 1 turn LED on

    if (receivedChar == '2')
    {
        digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
        active = false;
    } // if it's a 2 turn LED off
} // if it is a 3 flash the LED
```

Comment: yes i set it for delay(300), but my problem is for loop is not working int it.

Comment: if (receivedChar == "1") 
{
     while (receivedChar=="1") {
     digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);   // set the LED on
     delay(200);                  // wait for a second
     digitalWrite(LED, LOW);    // set the LED off
     delay(200);
     
     }
  }// if it's a 1 turn LED on
  if (receivedChar == "2") {
   
    digitalWrite(LED, LOW);}
  } // if it's a 2 turn LED off                     i am unable to OFF this loop with recievedChar"2"

Comment: @AlfredKommina I changed my answer with what I hope to be more towards what you are asking

Comment: @AlfredKommina I tried to incorporate what I understood from your comment

Comment: blinking is not working. it is just blinked once it is not looping

Comment: you copied the last version I posted? I made an edit an hour ago. In principle as long as you declare both variables as `static` and keep the switching of the `active` boolean inside the `if (mySerial.available())` it should only change its behavior if you are explicitly sending another char

Comment: yes but no continuous blinking, i also caalled a blinking function to that if statement but nothing happened. I don't know why  this much of  difficulty   :(

Comment: @AlfredKommina I posted another edit with a complete sketch which does what I understand that you are asking. If it doesn't, then you are doing things in your code in addition that you are not disclosing.

Comment: wooow you made it  Erik. Thank you very much I got it now. please explain me why that code doesn't worked?

Comment: @AlfredKommina the original code you posted relied on your own `for` loop to do the blinking, but this loop will simply run until the end unless there is a `break;` statement  or sth like that to interrupt it. This is why others and also I suggested that you simply rely on the arduino to do the looping, as the `loop` function will in any case run continuously.

Comment: @AlfredKommina in case this answer solves your problem, you can consider accepting it by clicking on the hollow checkmark at the top of the answer (http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). In case my or another answer was useful, you can also upvote one or more answers (http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use `String` and append the single characters and use `Serial.available() > 0` with a short `delay` as loop condition. I hope that this is going to help you.

```
int led = 13; 

void setup(){
    pinMode(led, OUTPUT); 
    Serial.begin(9600); 
    Serial.flush();
}

void loop()
{
    String receivedChars = "";

    while (Serial.available() > 0){
        receivedChars += (char) Serial.read(); 
        delay(5); 
    }

    if (receivedChars == "1"){
        digitalWrite(led, HIGH); 
    }
    else if (receivedChars == "2"){
        digitalWrite(led, LOW); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. i want **for loop** to work here. it is not looping continuously unless I remove that second condition. Suggest me something to stop for loop in **if condition**

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** Seeing the discusion in other answers, seems like you want to make a LED blink when received a `1` and stop blinking when received a `2`. First you should edit the original question, because sometimes you write `digitalWrite(LED, HIGH)` and sometimes it's `digitalWrite(buz, HIGH)`. That's confusing if you are using the same LED in the same pin.

Then I would suggest this code.

```
boolean blink = false;
byte state = 0;

void loop()
{
    if (mySerial.available()) // there is some data to read
    {
        receivedChar = mySerial.read();
        switch (receivedChar)
        {
            case '1':
                blink = true;
                break;
            case '2':
                blink = false;
                digitalWrite(LED, LOW); //turn off LED
                break;
        }
    }
    if (blink)
    {
        state ^= 1; //switch bit using xor operator
        digitalWrite(PED, state);
    }
    delay(500);
}
```

Hope it's easy to understand. If not, feel free to ask.

---

**OLD POST**: Are you sure it's not looping? May be `if (receivedChar)` condition is always false? Send some debugging info through serial port to check it.

Also, the `loop()` function is an infinite loop, there's no need to add one more. Just check `if (mySerial.available())`.

Seems like you want to make some sound while the LED is on, you can use the [Tone](http://arduino.cc/en/pmwiki.php?n=Reference/Tone) function for that.

I would suggest something like this:

```
void loop()
{
    if (mySerial.available()) // there is some data to read
    {
        receivedChar = mySerial.read();
        if (receivedChar == '1')
        {
            mySerial.println("Received a 1"); // for debugging
            digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
            tone(buz, 1000, 500);
        }
        if (receivedChar == '2')
        {
            mySerial.println("Received a 2"); // for debugging
            digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
        }
    }
}
```